# VS-code personal grammar extension : add cross-theme custom styling

Tags: syntax, vscode-extensions, grammar, styling, tmlanguage

I am in the process of writing a VS-Code syntax extension for a small language of mine. So far, so good, but I wonder whether it is possible to style certain elements in a cross-theme fashion.

---

This is a general question, but my specific need may pose another distinct problem. In the target language, blank lines are significant. I would like to style any sequence of blank lines (i.e., `(?<=\n)\s*\n`) by drawing a single horizontal rule across this sequence. The CSS could be something like :

```css
.blank-line::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px dashed black;
  }
```

Is there any way to attach such a CSS snippet to a tmLanguage grammar? Again, this should work independently from the user theme.